# How to specify renderer as SVG?

Tags: vega-lite

I am using a clone of [this VEGA-lite example](https://bl.ocks.org/domoritz/raw/455e1c7872c4b38a58b90df0c3d7b1b9/) and its chart spec as reference,   and added the `renderer` option

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "description": "A simple ...",
  "..ETC..": "...",
  "renderer": "svg"
}
```

But chart stay as PNG... How to use `renderer` option?

---

PS: the [online spec](https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json) have no `renderer` definition...  there are some confusion about VEGA-lite and [VEGA-view](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The renderer is not a property of the Vega-Lite specification, but rather a [Vega-Embed option](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#options).

How to specify it depends on how you are rendering your chart. For example, if you [open the chart in the vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/bar), you can choose the SVG renderer from the *Settings* menu in the upper right.

If you are generating HTML directly, you can pass the embed options to the `vegaEmbed` call; for example:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>

<body>  
  <div id="vis"></div>

  <script>
    const spec = "bar.vl.json";
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, {renderer: "svg"})
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(console.warn);
  </script>
</body>
```

It is also possible to express Vega-Embed options within the `usermeta` field of the chart specification itself; for example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "usermeta": {"embedOptions": {"renderer": "svg"}},
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

This should work correctly in any vega-embed call (but won't work, for example, in the vega editor, which uses a different rendering approach).